# Trying to find a horror novel involving a group of boys and a seance

Tags: story-identification, books, horror, soft-sci-fi

The only  details I can remember about this book is that there is a group of boys in a high school horror movie fanclub who decide to try a seance and end up summoning a demon. 
It would be an older book, as early as the 70s up to as late as the 90s I'd say.
If anyone knows of the title of this book or who the author might be please respond

Edit: The only other things I can remember from the book involve one of the main characters getting heavily bullied and a scene later on where the monster takes the shape of a young woman on the beach to seduce and kill another man. Hopefully this helps in some way

Comment: Welcome to the site. This [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) here might help jog your memory. Could you take a look and [edit] in any more details you can remember? Every little bit helps us.

Comment: There was a movie with this plot (Night of the Demons) but I'm not finding a novelization.

Comment: No its not that one unfortunately, thank you though. I just wish I could remember at least one of the characters names but it has been at least 12 years since I read the book. I have been searching incessantly but can't seem to find it

Comment: This almost sounds like https://www.amazon.com/Seance-Dark-Summons-Book-ebook/dp/B00EV84CGA#productDescription_secondary_view_div_1513240910579 , but it's too new...